# Coefficients of a vector field in a basis of left invariant vector field in $\operatorname{U}(n)$ as traces.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Consider a vector field $v$ on the Lie group $\operatorname{U}(n)$ and consider the collection of left invariant vector fields $(X_\alpha)$ given by the usual basis $(e_\alpha)$ of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$. The vector field $v$ can then be expressed as $\sum f_\alpha X_\alpha$ for some smooth functions $f_\alpha$ .

Suppose now that we have a concrete expression for $v(g)$, for example $v(g) = g - g^\ast$ which is indeed a skew-hermitian matrix, i.e. an element of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$. My question is the following : is there a way to get easily the $f_\alpha$'s? From playing around with examples I feel like there should something involving the trace of the product of $X_\alpha$ and $v(g)$ or something like this.

Am I totally off the mark?

EDIT: I thought about it a bit more and I think I got what I want.

In general, if you have a vector space $V$ equipped with an inner product $\langle -,- \rangle$ and a linear isomorphism $\phi : V \rightarrow W$, you can compute the coefficient of $w = \sum f_i w_i$ as $f_i  = \langle \phi^{-1} w, v_i\rangle$ where $v_i$ is an orthogonal basis.

Now there is real valued inner product on $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ given by $$\langle A,B\rangle = Tr(AB^\ast) = -Tr(AB)$$
and for every $g \in \operatorname{U}(n)$ we have an isomorphism of vector spaces from $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ to $T_g\operatorname{U}(n)$ given by $dL_g$, the differential of left multiplication by $g$. Let's say that the basis $(e_\alpha)$ of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ was orthonormal with respect to the above  inner product. By the general consideration discussed above, we can then compute $f_\alpha(g)$ by
$$f_\alpha(g) = \langle dL_{g^{-1}}(v(g)),e_{\alpha}\rangle = -Tr(g^{-1}v(g)e_\alpha)$$

Does it sound right?

Comment: Ultimately, this question is about computing coordinates for a vector given a basis.  Are you struggling to understand how the problem reduces to that task?  Or are you asking whether there is a natural inner product with which to compute the coordinates?

Comment: I think my question is more about the whether there is a natural inner product with which we can compute the coordinates. Indeed in some example I can work out what the coefficients are, but this gets quite hard the more complicated the vector field is. Hence the question about whether there is a more systematic way to find them.

Comment: I have added an edit which I think is an answer to my question. If this is not the case it atleast has the merit of precising a bit more my question.